# 555 flyback - question about efficiency

Tags: 555, flyback

How can I improve this scheme to reduce consumption? MOSFET is 4N0403[image]

Comment: What are your load and all loss incl L loss (DCR) specs?

Comment: I don't understand the question, I'm a beginner. Out i need 3v 100 mA.

Comment: Have you read how to switch DC to DC circuits yet?  There are a lot of problems with 16A 90% duty cycle in DCM drawing hundreds of watts to create 0.3 W. Specs mean Max inrush current, Peak input power, output power , load regulation error.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is don't use a 555, use something with feedback. LT and Maxim have some pretty good flyback controllers.

Comment: You cannot design anything without detailed specs. What are they?

Comment: Is this a boost or buck voltage? Does it need to be isolated?  What is output power over time and input power over time that you expect?

Comment: In 5v DC / Out 3v 100 mA AC.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the NE555, it's easily accounting for 10% of power consumption already; on top of many other reasons it's unsuitable.  (If you must, 555s can be used as a switchmode controller, with a lot of help; but it's still rather inferior to a proper one.  It's also maybe not the best building block for learning, if you're looking to construct the inner workings of better-known controllers like say UC3843.  Which, whether doing so with logic, discretes or 555s -- is an exercise I do recommend!)

Offhand, CS5171 or friends might be suitable here, albeit rated much more current than you're looking for.  Better options can be found in a supplier search.

Comment: I use TL555i (low power consumption cmos version). It is impossible for me to believe that a circuit consisting of two transistors (Royer Oscillator) can be used for a low power converter, and the IC 555 is rejected by everyone. This circuit is easy to find and in 10 years, the dedicated circuits will not be found and in a few years they will not be produced.

Comment: the 555 is simply not the type of device you need, Miau. End of story.